# "Must be" with a meaning like "must do"

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

I see that `somebody must do something` usually means that someone is obliged to do something. I also see that `you must be kidding me` means that it is highly likely that `you are kidding me`.

But can `Alex must be working on the project` mean an obligation (e.g. Alex must work on the project but with a sense of continuity) ?

Answer (score 3):

A frequent use of *must* is to express deduction, and I would say that that is what it is doing in *Alex must be working on the project*.

Obligation would be expressed by something like *Alex really must work hard on the project (if he wants to get it completed in time)*.

Comment: The intended senses are usually self-evident: _I must be leaving_ (It is imperative that I leave) v _You must be the manager_ (as Barrie says, expressing deduction). However, sometimes context is needed to disambiguate (We must be getting off [now] / We must be getting off [at the next stop]).

Answer (score 1):

*Must* is a [Modal Auxiliary Verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html).
(The other modals in English are *may, might, can, could, will, would, shall*, and *should*.
What follows applies to all of them, not just *must*.)

All modals have two different types of meaning:,

- one meaning, called the ***Epistemic*** sense of the modal,
  deals with possibility and probability
  e.g, (using *may* and *must* as examples):
  *This may be the place* (*may* = logically possible)
  *This may not be the place* (*may not* = possibly not)
  *This must be the place* (*must* = logically necessary)
  *This must not be the place* (*must not* = logically impossible)

and

- another meaning, called the ***Deontic*** sense of the modal,
  deals with permission and obligation
  e.g,
  *You may attend the prom.* (*may* = permitted to)
  *You may not attend the prom.* (*may not* = forbidden to)
  *You must attend the prom.* (*must* = obliged to)
  *You must not attend the prom.* (*must not* = forbidden to)

As you can see, negatives have very complex patterns with modals,
but modals are plenty complex all by themselves.

Deciding which one is intended is a matter of interpretation and context, and certainly active predicates with human agent subjects, like *He must do it*, are more likely to be deontic, while stative predicates, like *He must be late*, are more likely to be epistemic.

However, this is not true in all cases; consider for example

- *He **must do** this every morning.* (*must* = logically necessary)
- *He **must be** at work by 07:40.* (*must* = obliged to)